# How to scale an integer to date with range and domain

Tags: d3.js

How can I scale a number to a date with range and domain? For example I want a number to be scaled to as a date at some point between 2 arbitrary dates.

I've tried this:

```
var min = new Date(2009, 1, 1);
var max = new Date(2012, 2, 2);
var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([0,100]).range([min,max]);
console.log(xScale(10));
```

The result is `Object {}` and I've tried with a linear scale too.

Comment: This isn't clear.  Can you give an example?

Comment: Define the domain with numbers and the range with `Date`s.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff this is what I've done but the scaled result is an empty object. hmm. input number is within domain too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `d3.time.scale()` the domain is supposed to be an array of dates (since those are in the "domain"  of the data) and range is numbers. You're trying to do the reverse, which isn't supported. You need:

```
xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([min,max]).range([0,100]);
```

Then `xScale(date)` turns a date into a number (e.g. pixel position).

Since you want to do the reverse, so you need:

```
xScale.invert(10) // returns Date
```

Lars pointed out that it's possible to do this with a linear scale (instead of time scale). It would look like this:

```
linearScale = new d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range([Number(min), Number(max)]);
```

You have to cast `min` and `max` into numbers for this to work. Then you can compute dates out of numbers this:

```
new Date( linearScale(10) )
```